# Large File reader and Sort by Frequency and then Order Alphabetic Effiencetly

Tags: python

I am stumped on how to approach reading and tokenizing a massive text file. Then output by frequency and order.

From what I understand, the best of reading a large file is by large chunks to the buffer.

```
def read_in():
    with open("text.txt","r") as file:
        for line in file:
            <deliminate line>
```

Would it be more efficient to use the built in function to remove certain characters and store it in a list or run a loop to check each character?

The main part where I am stump is the checking the frequency and alphabetizing. I tried using pythons built in functions:

```
c = Counter(a).most_common()
sort_w = sorted(c)
sorted_fw = sorted(c, key = lambda x : x[1], reverse = True)
```

This works, but it only reads a chunk near the last part of a big text.file. I'm unsure how to and where I need to create a database and constantly update it until the file read is finished.

Or do I have to something in the heap? I want to take care for efficiency, but unsure which is the best approach.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: 1. Which amount of data we're talking about? 1MiB? 1GiB? 1TiB? 2. Frequency of what? Letters? Words? Lines? The approach depends on the general metainformation.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you not worry that much about efficiency until you know you have a performance issue. Reading data from a hard disk is pretty slow compared to almost anything you do with it after it's been read. You can do pretty slow stuff and still end up with the disk-reading being the limiting factor on your performance (and there's not much other than hardware upgrades that can speed it up).

Comment: @Art The amount data be up to 1Gib. Frequency of word occurrence.